# Model Selection property between AIC and Mallow's $C_p$

Tags: statistics

Let us consider a set of linear models defined by the function
$Y_i = \beta X_i + \epsilon_i, \epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2).$
Take a model $S$, and define the training error of a given model as
$\hat{R}_\text{tr}(S) = \sum_{i=1}^n (\hat{Y}_i(S) - Y_i)^2.$
We define Mallow's $C_p$ statistic as
$$\hat{R}(S) = \hat{R}_\text{tr}(S) + 2|S|\hat{\sigma}^2,$$

where $|S|$ denotes the number of terms in the model $S$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2$
is the estimate of $\sigma^2$ obtained for the full model.
Consider the AIC function of a model to be $AIC(S) = l_S - |S|,$
where $l_S$  is the log-likelihood of the model evaluated at the MLE.

I would like to show that, given $\sigma$ as known, that
$\arg\max_S AIC(S) = \arg\min_S \hat{R}(S).$
I was having some trouble showing this statement using general unconstrained
optimization, in particular because I am not entirely sure how to handle
the derivative of the function for Mallow's $C_p$ given that we have $|S|$ in
the second term of that function. Is there a better way to show this particular
statement?

Comment: Is $|S|$ intended to mean the number of columns in the design matrix? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I believe it should be, seeing that they're referring to $|S|$ as the "number of terms."

Comment: "How to handle the derivative" may be the wrong question.  The number of columns is a discrete function of the matrix; maybe differentiation is not the thing to do. $\qquad$

Comment: I see no one's answering here, and I wonder if it would get a quicker answer on stats(dot)stackexchange(dot)com.  If it's still here tomorrow maybe I'll see what I can do with it. $\qquad$